# Reducing image in bytes while storing in database mvc2 c# 4.0

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2

I am uploading a user image in mvc2 web application. User can upload an image of any size e.g. 10MB or more. The uploaded images are getting stored in database AS `IMAGE` datatype. But before getting stored in the database I want to **reduce its size to 4MB**. How do I do this?

I have reduced the size the bytes of the image with the following code:

```
   if (file.ContentLength > 0)
        {

                        //Create byte Array with file len
                        var imgByte = new Byte[file.ContentLength];
                        //force the control to load data in array
                        file.InputStream.Read(imgByte, 0, file.ContentLength);



    System.IO.MemoryStream newImageStream = 
               new System.IO.MemoryStream(imgByte, 0, imgByte.Length); 

                        Image image = Image.FromStream(newImageStream, true); 

                        Bitmap resized = new Bitmap(image, new Size(800,600));



                System.IO.MemoryStream stream = new System.IO.MemoryStream();

                resized.Save(stream, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);

                        var imgBytes = new Byte[stream.Length];



                        customParentalHealthUser.ImageBytes = imgBytes;

                        stream.Close();
                        stream.Dispose();
                        resized.Dispose();
                    }
```

But while displaying the image, images are not showing up even though the reduced size is getting stored in the DB. I think while reducing the size, image is getting corrupt or else.

Kindly Suggest?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You never write down the stream into the byte array you are creating:

```
var imgBytes = new Byte[stream.Length];
```

Then what?

Use ToArray() to get the actual byte array instead:

```
var imgBytes = stream.ToArray();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can either rescale the image or save it as JPEG with a higher compression level.

If the image is larger than the expected displaying size I would start with rescaling the image. Then apply higher compression if necessary.

Comment: Can you please provide the code fot that? here is my code: if (Request != null)
                {
                    HttpPostedFileBase file = Request.Files["uploadimage"];
                    if (file != null)
                        if (file.ContentLength > 0)
                        {
                    var imgByte = new Byte[file.ContentLength];
                                                       file.InputStream.Read(imgByte, 0, file.ContentLength);
                            customParentalHealthUser.ImageBytes = imgByte;
                        }
                }

Comment: @Tarun, there are already about [100 examples](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bc%23%5D+resize+image) of how to resize images in c#.

Comment: But i need to reduce the bytes size of the image as I am storing the image in the database as bytes array?

Comment: @Tarun, if you resize to a smaller image the file size will also shrink.